Loading HDF5 model with load_model function is not working
I have a machine translation model and I am trying to deploy it using flask, but it keeps printing these errors, I search up what could cause them I found that may be be from the difference of versions between loading and training the model
(venv) C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation>python app.py
2024-07-25 15:22:51.788747: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-07-25 15:22:52.785890: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\core\embedding.py:93: UserWarning: Do not pass an `input_shape`/`input_dim` argument to a layer. When using Sequential models, prefer using an `Input(shape)` object as the first layer in the model instead.
  super().__init__(**kwargs)
2024-07-25 15:22:55.400982: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\app.py", line 10, in <module>
    model = load_model('model.h5')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py", line 189, in load_model
    return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\legacy_h5_format.py", line 133, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model = saving_utils.model_from_config(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
    return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 495, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 342, in from_config
    layer = saving_utils.model_from_config(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
    return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 495, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\rnn\bidirectional.py", line 314, in from_config
    config["layer"] = serialization_lib.deserialize_keras_object(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\serialization_lib.py", line 718, in deserialize_keras_object
    instance = cls.from_config(inner_config)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\rnn\gru.py", line 699, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\rnn\gru.py", line 505, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\rnn\rnn.py", line 204, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\machine translation\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 266, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to GRU: {'time_major': False}

I am working on a python of version 3.12.4 , and I trained my model on tensorflow and keras of versions 2.15.0 both but the environment versions are tensorflow 2.16.2 and keras 3.4.1, I tried to download same versions in my environment but it didn't work perhaps because of the version of python.  Any help is appreciated
this is the code of app.py:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import numpy as np
import pickle
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the model and tokenizers
model = load_model('model.h5')

with open('eng_tokenizer.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
    eng_tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)

with open('fre_tokenizer.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
    fre_tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)

# Define maximum sequence lengths
eng_seq_len = 20  # Set to your max length
fre_seq_len = 20  # Set to your max length

def translate(input_sentence):
    y_id_to_word = {v: k for k, v in fre_tokenizer.word_index.items()}
    y_id_to_word[0] = '<PAD>'
    sentence = eng_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([input_sentence])
    sentence = pad_sequences(sentence, maxlen=eng_seq_len, padding="post")
    prediction = model.predict(sentence)
    translated_sentence = ' '.join([y_id_to_word[np.argmax(x)] for x in prediction[0]])
    return translated_sentence

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/translate', methods=['POST'])
def translate_sentence():
    data = request.json
    input_sentence = data.get('sentence')
    if not input_sentence:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No sentence provided'}), 400

    translated_sentence = translate(input_sentence)
    return jsonify({'translated_sentence': translated_sentence})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


